# MS Access Query Across Multiple Tables Showing Reduced Results

Tags: ms-access

I have a master list of employees that I need to run a query for across several tables. Every time I add another table I get reduced results. I suspect this is because it is looking for results in all tables and only displaying if they exist in all tables. I need to show results even if it is blank.

```
Employee Table
Employee     Status
Employee 1   Active
Employee 2   Inactive
Employee 3   Active

FICO Records
Employee     Week      Score
Employee 1   7/19/20   150
Employee 2   7/19/20   150   
Employee 1   7/12/20   250
Employee 2   7/12/20   350
Employee 3   7/12/20   200

Scorecard Records
Employee 1   7/19/20   Great
Employee 2   7/19/20   Great
Employee 3   7/19/20   Great
Employee 1   7/12/20   Great
Employee 2   7/12/20   Great
Employee 3   7/12/20   Great
```

The expected result is this:
The table lists ALL active employees and displays the results for parameter week set to 7/19/20 in this example. Employee 2 is discarded as they are inactive. Employee 1 shows results across both columns as they have records in both tables. Employee 3 shows results only in Scorecard as they did not have a FICO record.

```
Employee     Week      FICO     Scorecard
Employee 1   7/19/20   150      Great
Employee 3   7/19/20            Great
```

These are the results I'm currently getting

```
Employee     Week      FICO     Scorecard
Employee 1   7/19/20   150      Great
```

Here is the code I built with the Query Design tool in MS Access. I've tried using left join and it doesn't alter the results. Help please.

```sql
PARAMETERS [Week Date] DateTime;
SELECT
   [DA Master].[DA Name],
   [DA Master].Status,
   [DA AMZL Scorecard].[Overall Tier],
   [DA Fico].Week,
   [DA Fico].FICO 
FROM
   (
      [DA Master] 
      INNER JOIN
         [DA AMZL Scorecard] 
         ON [DA Master].ID = [DA AMZL Scorecard].DA
   )
   INNER JOIN
      [DA Fico] 
      ON [DA Master].ID = [DA Fico].DA 
WHERE
   (
(([DA Master].Status) = "Active") 
      AND 
      (
([DA Fico].Week) = [Week Date]
      )
   )
ORDER BY
   [DA Master].[DA Name];
```

Comment: You are trying to include multiple many-to-many relationships in one query. You will never get what you want this way. Best to build a report/subreport. If you really want 1 dataset, will involve multiple queries. For starters, need a dataset of all possible employee/week combinations then join the FICO and Scorecard tables to that dataset with compound join on Employee and Week. Apply filter to that final dataset.

Comment: Or if Scorecard will always have all employee/week pairs, use it as primary table and join FICO and Employees to it. FICO would have to compound join on Employee and Week fields.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess the best way is to create multiple queries and join them in one report? That's the purpose of creating the query anyway.

Comment: +1 for using a parameter for [Week Date], -1 for blanks in table/field-names.Read on [Joins](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/join-tables-and-queries-3f5838bd-24a0-4832-9bc1-07061a1478f6). If you start your query with active employees you can LEFT JOIN on the other infos without losing an employee (only applies as long there is max one row for each employee/week combo).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a table of all Week dates? If not, a UNION query can accomplish that and create dataset of all employee/week pairs.

```
SELECT Employee, Week FROM Employees, FICO 
UNION SELECT Employee, Week FROM Employees, Scorecard;
```

Can include any other fields of interest from Employees table or include Employees table in subsequent queries.

Now use that query in another query that compound joins with FICO and Scorecard tables on Employee and Week fields.

Each SELECT is a Cartesian product query. Be aware, these types of queries can perform slowly.

Otherwise, either FICO or Scorecard would need to have a record for every employee/week pair so it could act as 'master' table that the other 2 tables could join to.